# Can I check whether the given number can be the sum of any arithmetic progression having n terms in it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures

Is it possible for a given number s to just check that Is there any possible arithmetic progression having n terms and sum of these n terms results in s.

where starting element and difference of AP must not be zero.

for eg:

s = 24 & n = 4

yes, it is possible where AP is 3 5 7 9.

**Note:** I just want to check whether it is possible or not . No need to find the actual array.  0 < n < 10^9 & 0 < s < 10^18.

My Attempt:

we know that sum of an AP is equal to s = n(first+last)/2;

therefore first+last = 2*s/n;

2*s/n should be an integer.

we also know that last = first+(n-1)diff;

so my expression becomes 2*first + (n-1)diff = 2*s/n;

first = (2*s/n - (n-1)diff)/2; and it should be an integer for a particular value of diff.

this is my approach to doing this but its time complexity is too large to cover 10^18.

Please help. :)

Comment: Show us your attempts to do this.

Comment: ya sure I will edit this post please wait...

Comment: Are there any requirements to the step of the progression? Is 6+6+6+6 a legitimate answer?

Comment: This question is was recently tested here: https://www.codechef.com/SNCKEL16/problems/ARITHM

Comment: Yes difference of AP should not be zero

Comment: @LogicStuff {6,6,6,6} is a valid arithmetic progression and always will be. One with a common difference of zero. However it doesn't satisfy the requirements of the question.

Comment: @quirk you are right, I still wonder people solved this problem.

Comment: @Lucky Please mention all the constraints properly when posting a question. Also this is more suited for [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think my answer is correct, but you might want to ask this on the mathematics site, tagged with "number theory". I think the full proof might be quite intricate.

Comment: Should all involved numbers be integer? natural (integer>0) ?

Comment: Yes, off course if we take 0 as an element than the AP will reduce to n-1 terms.

Comment: It helps to see that `s/n == 6 == average{3,5,7,9}`. In general, for odd `n` the progression {... s/n - 2*x, s/n - x, s/n, s/n + x, s/n + 2* x, ... }` clearly has average `s/n` because every pair around the middle has that average. For even `n`, there's no middle element, the progression then is `... s/n-3x/2, s/n-x/2, s/n+x/2, s/n+3x/2 ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1: `a` and `d` are real numbers**

Using *s* for the sum, *n* for the number of terms, *a* for the first term and *d* for the difference between terms, you get the result

`2 * s / n = 2 * a + (n - 1) * d`

This gives you one degree of freedom. So you can see that it's *always* possible to pick an *infinite* set of *a* and *d* values that satisfies this result.

**Case 2:  `a` and `d` are integer numbers**

You can see from my result that if `a` and `d` are constrained to be **integers**, then the decomposition is only possible if the left hand side of this equation is *also* an integer; that is `2 * s` is a multiple of `n`. (In your case, `2 * s` is 48 which is a multiple of 4. So yes, there exists an integral `a` and `d` in that case).

Comment: 4 divides 48, not the opposite.

Comment: @Nelxiost: oops. I told you I was rusty.

Comment: @4386427 `14 = (-1)+0+1+2+3+4+5`.

Comment: @4386427 `21 = (-3)+(-1)+1+3+5+7+9`

Comment: @Nelxiost - nice one :-)

Comment: TI think the real case has one degree of freedom. You can pick either a and get d, or vice versa. Two degrees of freedom means you can pick them independently. But yes, even one degree of freedom gives you an infinite set.

Comment: @Bathsheba Can I have your email? Or I can give you mine

Answer (score 1):

Let `a` be the initial term of the progression and `d` its common difference. You want to solve the [linear diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)

```
n * a + (n*(n-1)/2) * d = s
```

The solution will exist if and only if `s` is a multiple of`gcd(n, n*(n-1)/2)`.

If `n` is odd, `gcd(n, n*(n-1)/2) = n * gcd(1, (n-1)/2) = n`.

If `n` is even, `gcd(n, n*(n-1)/2) = (n/2) * gcd(2, n-1) = n/2`.

In any case, the solution exists if and only if `2 * s` is a multiple of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible in every case but if you can provide some more data then it can.
because there is multiple possibilities of same AP sum.
so in case you will give some hint it is possible

Comment: 2*s being divisible by n is a sufficient condition in any case.

Comment: We just have to find out one of these possibilities. If it is possible than Yes else No.